# Next/Previous Image In The same folder In The Android

Tags: java, android

I need To Move To Next/Previous Image Of same Folder in My Android Device.
For this I think I need To get the Index Of element(images/document) etc.
So How Can I get The Index Of any Document In a folder In Android Device, or Is There any different Method through which I can Move To next/ Previous Image In the Same Folder In Android Device.......... 
Efforts will Be Highly Appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

you can get images from specified folder and store it in the list 
now you can move previous, next by using index of the list
just tryout this method if it works means fine

this is my suggestion

Comment: His question itself is: "How Can I get The Index Of any Document In a folder In Android Device." So what's new in your suggestion?

Comment: read that once again friend he asked for images in 1st line, so only i replied like get images from that folder and store it list. we can get the index of the current image by checking some conditions and also using loops. using that index of the image in the list we stored previously. we can move image to pre or next by increment or decrementing the index

Comment: that means you have just read 1st line. Read full question fully.